# TYPO3 rte_ckeditor plugin

Tags: ckeditor, typo3

I try to insert a FontAwesome plugin in CKEditor.
https://github.com/brstuff/ckawesome

```
  externalPlugins:
    ckawesome:
      resource: "EXT:siteconfig/Resources/Public/JavaScripts/RTE/Plugins/ckawesome/plugin.js"
```

I copied the Font Awesome fonts and CSS in that folder and the RTE gives a button which popups the dialog.

However the console gives me a "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"

In plugin.js is:

```
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('ckawesome') + 'resources/select2/select2.full.min.js');
```

This path is correct, however should a script in this way be loaded on a different method with TYPO3 CKEditor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, perhaps this extension solves the issue

https://github.com/DirkPersky/rte-ckeditor-fontawesome

it add font awesome, so no need for you to reinvent that wheel :-)

Second, if you really want to found out why your own solution doesn't work, try and find out, what path

```
CKEDITOR.scriptLoader.load(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath('ckawesome') + 'resources/select2/select2.full.min.js');
```

resolves to, perhaps something is wrong there.

Comment: Thx I indeed looked at the version of DirkPersky, his plugin doesnt give a javascript error.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem, please mark is as answered, so other can benefit from it :-)